# v-for: _vm.property is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple component that call an API to get some cards so I can use them in the template.

```
<template>  
    <div v-if="apiok">
      <span  :v-for="(card,i) in listcards" :key="card.multiverseidEnglish">test{{card.nameEnglish1}}</span>
    </div>
</template> 


<script>

  import { CARD_ALL } from '@/services/collection';

  export default {   
    data() {
      return {        
        listcards: this.getList(),
        card: null,
        apiok: false
      };
    },
    methods: {
      async getList(){
        let returnAPI = await CARD_ALL();
        this.apiok= true;
        return returnAPI.data.content;
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getList();

    }
  };
</script>
```

Also the API call in @/services/collection :

```
import axios from 'axios'

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/cards/all';

const findAll = async () => {
  let url = apiUrl;

    try {
    let cards = await axios.get(url);

    return cards;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }

};


export const CARD_ALL = findAll;
```

The API returns the right data

When I run this code I have the following error :

```
TypeError: "_vm.card is null"
```

What am I missing here? Is it because of the async?

Comment: There shouldn't be a colon at the start of `:v-for`.

Comment: Nice thanks! Ok I removed it and I don't have "_vm.card is null". Instead I have "card is undefined". Any idea?

Comment: That would likely be because `listcards` is a promise and not an array. `async` methods return promises, so `listcards: this.getList(),` just assigns a promise to `listcards`.

Comment: Ok I just directly assigned listcard the data returned by the APi and it works. Thanks a lot!